# How do I update the UI before a turn in a game

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having trouble updating the UI in the middle of the turn. I'm currently trying to use a coroutine to choose a piece, but something is not going right. I want the player to click on the dice to roll them, so a new turn can begin, this works fine. The problem is the turn itself.

I have a function that sets an outside variable named "highLightedTiles" with every tile that is available for a move, it also creates a suspended coroutine and saves its continuation in another outside variable named "chosenTile".

```
 suspend fun newTurn() {
    currTurn++
    dices.rollDices()

    moveTurn() //Is a suspended function

    endTurn()
}
```

```
private suspend fun moveTurn() {
    currPlayer.pieces.forEach { p ->
        if (p.info.isInPlay)
            highlightedTiles.add(board.getTile(p.position!!))
    }

    selectedAlly = suspendCoroutine<Tile> { c -> chosenTile = c }.piece

    setReachableTiles(dices.first * 2, selectedAlly!!)
}
```

The problem is the board, not updating itself, with the new highlights, and if it doesn't update itself the tiles are not clickable which means the continuation can't be resumed.

```
@Composable
suspend fun gameView(game: Game) {
    paintBoard(game.board)

    val dices = remember { game.dices }

    paintHighlights(game.highlightedTiles, game.highlightType) { t ->
        game.chosePiece(t)
    }

    diceView(dices) { game.newTurn() }
}
```

```
@Composable
suspend fun diceView(dices: Dices, onClick: suspend () -> Unit) {
    val m1 = Modifier.clickable { onClick() }
    val img1 = "dices/dice${if (dices.first == 0) "null" else dices.first}"
    Image(painterResource("$img1.png"), img1, m1)

    val m2 = Modifier.clickable { onClick() }
    val img2 = "dices/dice${if (dices.second == 0) "null" else dices.second}"
    Image(painterResource("$img2.png"), img2, m2)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the UI is getting blocked"? Maybe try val dices by remember { mutableStateOf (game.dices) } instead of val dices = remember { game.dices }.

Comment: I will re-write my  question, I was tired last night maybe I can clear thing out.